# How to use Expression.IfThenElse in C#

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a method in a repository:

```
Query<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T,bool>> function)
```

When i call it, I want to use different Expressions based on a condition.

I tried:

```
m_Repository.Query<MyObject>(x => x.Infos.Count > 1 ? 
x.Infos.Any(y => y.Info.Name.StartsWith(s)) :
x.Name.StartsWith(s));
```

but then it always executes the else part. I figured I had to use Expression.IfThenElse, but I cannot make it work. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "That doesn't seem to work" doesn't really help us much. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question with a much fuller description.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Expression.Condition

Comment: I have tried it, but it returns a ConditionalExpression - that doesn't help me.